# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 33 Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: dynamic, sql-server-2014, ssms-2012

First time I am trying dynamic query as pivot table. I solve many error using SO. Now I am stuck in following *common error*.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

So I can't discover what mistake is..!

**pivotEx**

```
create table pivotEx (name varchar(1), mark int, subject varchar(1))

insert into pivotEx values
 ('a', 70,'t')
,('a', 80,'e')
,('b', 60,'t')
,('c', 80,'t')
,('c', 90,'e')
,('c', 40,'m')
```

**Static Query**(working fine)

```
 select name, [e],[m],[t] from(  
  select name, mark, subject from pivotEx 
 ) f
 pivot
 ( sum(mark) for subject in ([e],[m],[t])
 ) p
```

**Dynamic Query**(what I am try)

```
declare @col varchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(100)
set @col = N''
select @col +=  ',' + col from (select distinct quotename(subject) col from pivotex) colp
select @col=SUBSTRING(@col,2,len(@col))
select  @col
set @sql = 
N'select name, '+@col+' from(  
 select name, mark, subject from pivotEx 
) f
pivot
( sum(mark) for subject in ('+@col+')
) p'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Note:

1. Using SQL Server 2014.
2. Using SSMS 2012.
3. I am new to Dynamic Query.

Thanks,

TamilPugal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `@sql` data type because your query string is truncated:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(MAX)
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c777cb982c5678203b829cc831aa7c83)**

---

It is a good practice to print your query with `SELECT/PRINT` before execution.

```
PRINT @sql
-- select name, [e],[m],[t] 
   from(select name, mark, subject from pivotEx ) f pivot( sum(mark) for subje
```